# Array and loop management

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here I have written simple program but I have little issue in managing it.

I have 6 points, for each point I want to calculate distance to other points.

[DEmo - http://ideone.com/mYl30O](http://ideone.com/mYl30O)

code:

```
<?php
$a_points = array(
    array(0, -1),
    array(-2, 3),
    array(4, 0),
    array(3, 1),
    array(5, 2),
    array(0, 1),
);
$k = 0;
$a_sum_dists = array();
$sum = array();
foreach ($a_points as $i => $pt1) {
    list($x1, $y1) = $pt1;
    //$sum = 0;
    foreach ($a_points as $j => $pt2) {
        if ($j == $i) continue;
        list($x2, $y2) = $pt2;
        $sum[$k] = pow($x2- $x1, 2) + pow($y2- $y1, 2);
        $k++;
    }
    //$a_sum_dists[$i] = $sum;
}

?>
```

What I want:

1. for each point, get distance to all other points. Then print point which is at min distance. If more then one such points, print all
2. Now we have min distance points for each point. So now prints points which appears most frequently as a min distance. If more then one such points, print all

Comment: To get the distance, you also need to take square root there. `sqrt(pow($x2- $x1, 2) + pow($y2- $y1, 2))`, also I believe if you want to know the points used for specific sums a counter is not the best way.

Comment: display your required output gives more clarity

Comment: @Pietu1998: thanks but if I skip using sqrt, even purpose of getting closest points can be preserved. If i am not wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now when you've specified algorithm in detail, I can suggest implementation for it:

```
$a_all_ids = array_keys($a_points);
$a_neibor_ids = array();
foreach ($a_points as $i => $pt1) {
    list($x1, $y1) = $pt1;
    $a_dists = array();
    foreach ($a_points as $j => $pt2) {
        if ($j == $i) continue;
        list($x2, $y2) = $pt2;
        $a_dists[$j] = pow($x2- $x1, 2) + pow($y2- $y1, 2);
    }
    $min_dist = min($a_dists);
    $a_neibor_ids = array_merge(
        $a_neibor_ids,
        array_keys(array_filter($a_dists, function ($v) use ($min_dist) {
            return $v == $min_dist;
        }))
        );
}

$a_counts = array_count_values($a_neibor_ids);
$max_count = max($a_counts);

$a_result_points = array_intersect_key(
    $a_points, 
    array_filter($a_counts, function ($v) use ($max_count) {
        return $v == $max_count;
    })
);
```

Notations:

- `$a_dists` - distances from the current point to the rest points.
- `$a_neibor_ids` - for each point we find its nearest point(s).
  `$a_neibor_ids` is union of all such points (including duplicates).
- `$a_counts` - numbers of occurences of each value from $a_neibor_ids.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/PRUCZg)

Comment: thanks a ton. Can you please add comments in code?? in ideone? little complex php DS.

Comment: Added some explanation

Comment: can you please suggest name for this algo? want your opinion

Comment: Something like "most frequent neighbor" or "most frequent nearest point" algo

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward implementation of what you have described is:

```
$points = [
    [0, -1],
    [-2, 3],
    [4, 0],
    [3, 1],
    [5, 2],
    [0, 1],
];

$max_closest = [];

foreach ($points as $i => list($ax, $ay)) {
        $min_dist = INF;
        $dists = [];

        foreach ($points as $j => list($bx, $by)) {
                if ($i == $j) {
                        continue;
                }
                $dists[$j] = $sq_dist = ($bx - $ax) * ($bx - $ax) + ($by - $ay) * ($by - $ay);

                if ($sq_dist < $min_dist) {
                        $min_dist = $sq_dist;
                }
        }

        // select closest points
        foreach (array_keys($dists, $min_dist, true) as $key) {
                print_r($points[$key]); // print point

                // keep track of points that were closest
                if (isset($max_closest[$key])) {
                        ++$max_closest[$key];
                } else {
                        $max_closest[$key] = 1;
                }
        }
}

rsort($max_closest);

foreach (array_keys($max_closest, $max_closest[0], true) as $key) {
        print_r($points[$key]); // print point
}
```

Comment: @Programming_crazy Oh, you need 5.5 to use `foreach($array as list($foo, $bar)` :) see http://3v4l.org/2Z7cj